# Getting a modified type from a class marked by decorator

Tags: typescript, generics, decorator, reflect-metadata

I have a class defined like:

```js
class Person {
    @OneToOne()
    pet: Animal;
}
```

Is there a way to get a modified type which looks like this? (Adding `{propertyKey}Id: string` to properties by marking it with a decorator)

```js
// Using generics
type ModifiedPerson = SomeGeneric<Person>

// Or maybe using functions?
type ModifiedPerson = typeof someFunc(Person);

// Equivalent as:
type ModifiedPerson = {
    pet: Animal,
    petId: string,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is not properly possible with typescript today. There is a [pending issue open since 2015 on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881).

`@Decorators` have no effect on type.